# Issues with dependencies when installing wine

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

When I was trying to install wine on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I get this error:

```
jayden@UbuntuInstall:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried installing this dependency to then get another error saying I need more dependencies.

```
jayden@UbuntuInstall:~$ sudo apt install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when I go deeper into it I keep getting more missing dependency errors. I also don't know how to remove the broken packages as everything I have tried hasn't worked.

I don't know how to get the older version of wine that's intended for 20.04 as that may be the issue.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this.

Comment: Can I confirm the version of Ubuntu you’re using? Your question says 20.04, but the error message references Hirsute, which is 21.04 

Comment: Nope, I'm definatly on 20.04.2

Comment: I've just thought of something. There may have been a chance that I accidentally installed the repository for 21.04. How would I check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to install Wine from WineHQ, you need to follow the instructions from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.

You need to make sure that you add the repo for the correct system version, and that seems to be the issue in your case. Check out the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, find one containing the Wine repo and replace in it all occurrences of `hirsute` with `focal` in your case for Ubuntu 20.04 (you can verify the name of the release you are using with the command `lsb_release --codename`).

In addition to that, ensure that you do:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

before installing any new packages, to ensure outdated packages aren't causing any issues during the installation of the new ones. For example, dependencies on the new package may reference new versions of dependencies about which `apt` won't know without updating, leading to the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have installed a wrong repository.
first you need to delete that and then install the right one.
first open your repository list in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

scroll down the page to find this lines of code or similar:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

in your case probably you have installed "hirsute main". in that case you need to remove two lines and save (ctrl+s) list and exit (ctrl+x). also if you have installed other versions they are will be there aswell. if so keep right lines and just delete others. if you have'nt install other version just run the right code.
eg: (for focal version)

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

update packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

then install wine:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: nope this just creates the same error
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) not to  be Installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) 
                         Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) 
                         Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386
                         R: libglu1-mesa:i386 or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         R: libosmesa6:i386 
                         R: libsane:i386 or
                                     libsane1:i386
                         R: libxslt1.1:i386