# Unable to remove Wine: no packages to remove

Tags: 20.04, wine

I am trying to uninstall wine using Ubuntu Software store but it keeps saying
"Unable to remove Wine: no packages to remove"

Edit: Commands:

```
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install winehq-stable
[sudo] password for swastik: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 is to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 7.0.0.0~hirsute-1)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 7.0.0.0~hirsute-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.7).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install wine-stable-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 is to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install wine-stable-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 is to be installed
                     Recommends: libodbc1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libosmesa6 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Tried to install it again. Its showing this now: E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Search on that error message. It's common when folks add third-party sources, and oft-answered.

Comment: Are you doing this in WSL? Adding a windows emulator to an ubuntu system running on windows?

Comment: No I am doing this in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Then why are you using a microsoft repo? I suggest examining and rationalizing your sources list.

Comment: I just pasted the command from WineHQ and its showed me microsoft repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with dependencies when installing wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347125/issues-with-dependencies-when-installing-wine)

Comment: YES! IT DID!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to search for installed packages that contain the word "wine":

```
dpkg -l | grep wine
```

To be more accurate, you can search for packages that begin with the word wine:

```
dpkg -l | grep "ii  wine"
```

To uninstall a package, you can use the `apt purge` command. For example, if you want to uninstall the package `wine64`, use the following command:

```
sudo apt purge wine64
```

Finally, to delete your wine prefix, run the following commands:

```
cd
rm -r .wine
```

or

```
cd
rm -r .wine*
```

Comment: Its saying wine is not installed " swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep wine
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep "ii  wine"
swastik@Swas-PC-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt purge wine64
[sudo] password for swastik: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine64' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/home/swastik/.wine': No such file or directory

Comment: @GammaSpeed wine64 was an example. If wine packages are installed, they will be listed when you run the `dpkg` command. If no packages are listed, it is not installed. However, if a package is listed, then you will run the command to remove whatever package is listed. For example, if  `ii  wine` is listed, then you would run `sudo apt purge wine` If `ii wine-stable` is listed, you would run `sudo apt purge wine-stable` etc. . .

Comment: @GammaSpeed Okay good, it looks like it is not installed.

Comment: When Wine was downloading (from Ubuntu Software store), I had to cancel it due to some network issues. After this Software store was showing that Wine is downloaded but I couldn't find it in App Grid, so I decided to remove it but it displayed "Unable to remove wine: no packages to remove"

Comment: @GammaSpeed Okay, well it may have downloaded but it appears it did not install. If you want to install it, have you already tried to reinstall the package?

Comment: I tried to reinstall it but first I have to remove it but its not removing.

Comment: I tried downloading wine from commands but it was showing dependencies errors. I tried installing them but each of them showed more dependencies errors.

Comment: Please post the dependency errors in your question. Copy and paste the entire output. Thanks.

Comment: Posted the dependencies errors